# prop('checked', true) doesn't seem to work with input type radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

When I click a button. I show a view with Active status checked. But the code isn't working.

I'm unable to find the mistake here. Could someone help me out?
No matter what I try, the radio buttons are always unchecked when I call the function on button click.

**My Code:**

```js
$(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function() {
     $('#name').val('');
     $('#active').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <input type="radio" class="flat" id="active" name="status" value="true"> Active
  <input type="radio" class="flat" id="inactive" name="status" value="false"> Inactive
</div>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-success" >Add</button>
```

Comment: It would be nice to provide us also the element with id `#btn`

Comment: And $('#active').prop('checked', 'checked') ?

Comment: @WaldemarIce you missed a `'` at the end. But without the button also a `console.log('Hello World');` won't work

Comment: Your snippet seems to work fine

Comment: the code in the question works for me

Comment: cool, we got the button. Now may we have also the element with id `#name`?

Comment: So what is different with this code and the actual code? Do you have multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: I don't have other elements with the same Ids. I'm using datatables and bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I was using bootstrap. I removed class="flat" from input type. Now it's working, but I lost the styling.

Comment: Look for how is defined this `flat` class to find what is affecting the radios... And override only this parameter with a `!important`. So you will keep the rest of the styling. ;)